# Current limit and current gain bjt question

Tags: current, voltage-regulator, bjt, semiconductors

[image]

Contact potential of Vbe in Q2=Vbe-on
I worked out that the maximum current that can go through R2 is Vbe-on/R2. So my question is why does Q2 turn on when the emitter current of Q1 reaches this maximum current?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What is the voltage across R2?

When the voltage across R2 reaches Vbe-on, what happens with Q2?

Answer those questions and come back with more questions of your own if necessary.

As a side note, it is customary to place a low-value resistor (1k) in series with the base of Q2. This prevents damaging the base of Q2 when a sudden short occurs at the output.

Comment: how do i work out the voltage of R2? Vr2=Ir2*r2 and Ir2=Ie-Ib, but i don't know what Ib is do i?

Comment: Ignore current Ib2. It is so much smaller than the current through R2 that it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

> why does Q2 turn on when the emitter current of Q1 reaches this
>   maximum current?

Actually, it is not the maximum but the limited! You can set the current by R2. 
And when Q1 Collector current increased, voltage difference of the E-B junction will increase so Q1 will be like shorted(Rce2 will decrease so much). When thats happens, E-B junction potential of the Q1 will decrease so Rce will increase, so the collector current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO3xKC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>